# useQuery doesn't fire on rerender

Tags: reactjs, apollo

I have a component:

```
// MovieOverview.tsx

const MovieOverview = () => {
  const [rerender, setRerender] = useState(false);
  const {loading, error, data} = useQuery(resolvers.queries.ReturnAllMovies);

  console.log('data: ', data);

  let movies: IMovie[] = data?.movies;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (movies) {
      console.log('movieVar: ', movieVar());
      movies = [...movies, movieVar()];
    }
    setRerender(!rerender);
  }, [useReactiveVar(movieVar)]);

  if (loading) return <p>loading</p>;
  if (error) return <p>Error! ${error.message}</p>;

  return (
    <div>
      {movies.length}
    </div>
  );
};
```

- In this component I have a `useQuery` that returns an array of objects (movies).
- I have a `useEffect` that should add a object (movie) from my cache to the movies array when the `movieVar` is changed.
- There's also a `useState` that updates the template.

My cache:

```
// cache.tsx

import {InMemoryCache, ReactiveVar, makeVar} from '@apollo/client';
import {IMovie} from './movieseat';

export const cache: InMemoryCache = new InMemoryCache({
  typePolicies: {
    Query: {
      fields: {
        movies: {
          read() {
            return movieVar();
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
});

export const movieVar: ReactiveVar<IMovie> = makeVar<IMovie>({id: 1, original_title: '', backdrop_path: '', poster_path: '', release_date: ''});
```

And finally I have a component that adds a movie:

```
// addMovie.tsx

const [addMovieRes] = useMutation(resolvers.mutations.AddMovie);

addMovieRes({variables: {
  original_title: movie.original_title,
  tmdb_id: movie.id,
  poster_path: movie.poster_path,
}});

movieVar(movie);
```

When I add a movie, the `addMovie` component stores the movie in the database, the added movie is placed in the reactive variable: `movieVar`. In my `MovieOverview` component the `useEffect` is triggered and the passed in movie object shows up as expected. The problem is that the `useQuery` doesn't do anything.

On the initial component load I can see:

[image]

But when I add a movie that `ReturnAllMovies` query is not called again:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Might have resolved it, looks good so far. So there's a [`refetch`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#refetching) option.

> Refetching enables you to refresh query results in response to a particular user action, as opposed to using a fixed interval.

SO I updated my `useQuery`:

```
const {loading, error, data, refetch} = useQuery(resolvers.queries.ReturnAllMovies);
```

And added the refetch callback (?) to the `useEffect`:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (movies) {
      console.log('movieVar: ', movieVar());
      movies = [...movies, movieVar()];
    }
    refetch();
  }, [useReactiveVar(movieVar)]);
```

Now the `useQuery` is fired again and the data is updated.